# Is there a way to automatically update old Ruby on Rails queries to the newer syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

For example, update something from Rails 2 like

`Model.find(:first, :conditions => ["column_a = ? and column_b = ?", 'string', object.id])`

to a newer method that works such as

`Model.where(column_a: 'string', column_b: object.id).first`

I have a project where I need to update about a thousand more of these things than I originally thought. But I can't find any kind of gem, app, anything that can do these automatically. And it seems that with so many Rails apps upgrades someone would have. Anybody know of anything that can automate this process?

Comment: Even if there was a method I wouldn't trust it. That sort of stuff can get mangled really badly in a hurry. It's better to do it by hand. If you have a very specific pattern you can rewrite, use a regular expression. Many text editors support search and replace with one.

Comment: @tadman I understand why people shy away from automatic rewrites of such things. But when there's over 1,000 of them, doing it by handle is a tedious, tedious task.

Comment: Welcome to the happy, fun world of technical debt! If your code is still working then what you're talking about here is a luxury, it doesn't impact performance or code-correctness. I'd leave it as-is, but any time you're working on a file with code like this, clean it up and test it. If you have a style guide you're trying to adhere to, that's usually a good way to get these things stomped out over time.

Comment: If you're really intent on grinding these out of existence that could be a pretty significant undertaking. The cost of a mistake is really high, so unless there's tangible benefits other than just feeling better you're going to have to test your application top-to-bottom after such a huge rewrite. If you don't have tests, I'd steer clear of this venture completely.

Comment: @tadman The idea is to get to Rails 4.2. We've been upgrading the app from 2.x and already got a semi working version at 4.0.4. After using a Rails 3 plugin which was supposed to locate all these queries, and I manually rewrote the ones it found (around 800-1000). I thought I was done. Turns out the plugin was wrong.

Comment: Like that plugin you could patch the `find` method in your development environment to barf out warnings if it's detecting old-style arguments and, possibly, a suggested re-write if you can figure out how to do that reliably. That would make fixing it more a case of copy-paste than hand-editing everything. If it still works in 4.2 then I wouldn't worry.

Comment: @tadman That's the thing, it doesn't. After 4.0.4 that completely removed the ability to do a .find(:all or .find(:first.

Comment: You could stub in an adapter that re-writes it programmatically, taking `:conditions` and passing them through to `where`. Messy but perhaps effective. `conditions: [ ... ]` becomes `where([...])`.

Comment: @tadman Messy, hard to find, I could write it myself but some are extremely complicated queries. Idk, if it was that easy you'd think someone would have done it by now. I could use the official https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders gem. But with Rails 5 around the corner, it seems pointless since Rails says they won't support the band-aid gems at 5.

Comment: Totally feel your pain. I've had to claw several apps from Ruby 1.8 to 1.9 and Rails 2.x to 3.x and 4.x. Often the best approach is to force update, and just keep running tests until it breaks, then fix those tests more systematically. Then test a whole bunch more to be sure. `git grep` often comes in handy.

Comment: @tadman Yup, thanks Tadman